# Merge 2 arrays from different files

Tags: php, arrays

Don't ask why but I want to merge an array in a file, but the problem is the second array is located in another file. Ill try to explain better with examples below.

file1.php:

```
$array = [
    1,
    2,
    3
] + (array)include 'file2.php';
```

file2.php

```
return [4, 5, 6];
```

Comment: This should work.. whats the error?

Comment: it's an artisan(laravel) error inside the command-line, but it's a parse error on the line it with the plus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch everything I described I think I found the problem, I was using Laravel and tried to merge an array inside a class with the include function, which as far as I know is never going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In `file2.php`, assign it to a variable instead of returning it. That variable will be visible in your first file after you include the file there.

Then, use `array_merge()` to merge them together. As long as you don't have any conflicting keys (you don't even assign keys here, so shouldn't be a problem), there won't be any issues. The manual of `array_merge()` holds more details on this.

file1.php

```
include "file2.php";
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$array = array_merge($array, $file2_array);
```

file2.php

```
$file2_array = [4, 5, 6];
```

Output of `$array` in file1.php would then be

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

## References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case isn't the `include` - the problem is `+` which merge the array's by key and duplicate keys are removed.

You have two options to fix this.

**use array merge**

```
$array = array_merge([1,2,3], include 'file2.php');
```

**use arrays with unique keys**

```
$array = ['key1' => 'data'] + include 'file2.php';
```

with `file2.php`

```
return ['key2' => 'other data'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

File 1

```
return [
   'key1' => 'value2' 
];
```

Main file

```
$array1 = require "file1.php";
$array2 =  [
   'key2' => 'value2' 
];

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? See example http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-121